# Modifying properties of Attributes Table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, attribute-table

In my QGIS project I'm using vector layers that require a lot of data inputting/editing.

The problem is that some of the data I'm inputting varies greatly in matter of length and structure (various number of lines of text for example). When it comes to edit those lines in many objects or to compare the data in various objects it is painful to do it by selecting each object(line or point) separately. Instead of doing all this work by selecting each object and edit its properties I'm using Attributes Table.

I would like to know is there a way so Attributes Table remembered height and width of each column?

Is it possible to modify those properties in python?

And last but not least, do you think there is reasonable effort in writing plugin that extends Attributes Table for functionalities mentioned above.